# Antivirus for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, antivirus

I was wondering if it is necessary to use an Antivirus for Ubuntu 14.04 and which one should I use, I tried using the official documentation but the antivirus list there is for 10.04, I have no idea how to install ClamAV, I've tried what the ClamAV website says and what Ubuntu website says with no luck, I tried to find Avast for Linux but apparently it no longer exists D:

Answer (score 0):

For your safety you don't really need antivirus. But it is good to have one, just so you don't spread the windows viruses through USB sticks.
You can get Clam Tm from Ubuntu software center.